# Model Error in Using R Caret with numeric data

Tags: r, r-caret

I am new to R. I got a error while using Caret.

```
# load the library
library(mlbench)
library(caret)
mydata2 <-mydata[1:200,c(52, 56:59)]
mydata2
# load the dataset
# prepare training scheme
control <- trainControl(method="lm", number=10, repeats=3)
# train the model
model <- train(MtrRegActNetEngyDailyKwh~., data=mydata2,method="lvq", preProcess="scale", trControl=control)
# estimate variable importance
importance <- varImp(model, scale=FALSE)
# summarize importance
print(importance)
```

But, the result shows nothing..
[plot shows nothing..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aSEw.png)

Example of my data:

```
structure(list(MtrRegActNetEngyDailyKwh = c(16.736, 18.093), 
    Building = c(6, 6), numberofpeople = c(5, 5), pool = c(2, 
    2), typeofAC = c(1, 1)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

I am not sure why the model does not work... Can get some help?

**Update：**

I tried following code. It works.

```
model_nnet<-train(trainSetSmall[,predictors],trainSetSmall[,outcomeName],method='nnet')
importance <- varImp(model_nnet, scale=FALSE)
plot(importance)
```

I also want to test it in 'gbm' model.

```
model_gbm<-train(trainSetSmall[,predictors], trainSetSmall[,outcomeName],method='gbm')
importance2 <- varImp(model_gbm, scale=FALSE)
```

But, I got an error message..

```
Error Message:  > importance2 <- varImp(model_gbm, scale=FALSE)
Error in relative.influence(object, n.trees = numTrees) : 
could not find function "relative.influence"
```

I am not sure why it does not work... I just want to use other model to test again. Can I get some help?

Answer (score 2):

As the error states, you are using the wrong kind of model for your data. Learning Vector Quantization is only for classification modelling, not regression modelling. You need to select a different model given your data. See [this page](https://topepo.github.io/caret/available-models.html) of the caret documentation for all the available models in caret. Filter on regression to see all the regression models.

Comment: Thanks! I changed to "lm" for linear regression, but it still doesn't work..It shows nothing. Could you see my updated question? Thanks

Comment: @chen , Install package gbm.

Comment: Hi phiver, I've installed the package, but it still doesn't work... I also tried "lm", the result only shows the importance of one one not all factors. Is there a special parameter I need to define when use them? Thanks!